# How to use belongsTo in ember-model?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-model

I have created `FIXTURES` using ember-model, but i am not able to use following node on template

```
    "logged_in": {
        "id" : "1",
        "logged": true,
        "username": "sac1245",
        "account_id": "4214"
    }
```

I have implemented `belongsTo` relation for this node but it throwing one error : `Uncaught Error: Ember.Adapter must implement findQuery`
Here i have listed my model code :

```
Astcart.Application =  Ember.Model.extend({
    name: Ember.attr(),
    logo_url : Ember.attr(),
    list: Ember.hasMany('Astcart.List', {key: 'list', embedded: true}),
    logged_in: Ember.belongsTo('Astcart.Logged_in', {key: 'logged_in'})
});

    Astcart.List = Ember.Model.extend({
      name: Ember.attr()
    });

    Astcart.Logged_in = Ember.Model.extend({
      id: Ember.attr(),
      logged: Ember.attr(),
      username: Ember.attr(),
      account_id: Ember.attr()
    });

    Astcart.Application.adapter = Ember.FixtureAdapter.create();

    Astcart.Application.FIXTURES = [
        {
            "id"     : "1",
            "logo_url": "img/logo.jpg",
            "logged_in": {
                "id" : "1",
                "logged": true,
                "username": "sac1245",
                "account_id": "4214"
            },          
            "name": "gau",
            "list": [
                        {
                            "id"     : "1",
                            "name": "amit"
                        },
                        {
                            "id"     : "2",                 
                            "name": "amit1"
                        }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Template code :

```
    {{#each item in model}}
        {{item.name}}
        {{item.logged_in.logged}}                               
    {{/each}}
```

Router code :

```
  Astcart.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return Astcart.Application.find();
    }
  });
```

Can any one show me how to access data of above node in template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current fixture have the `logged_in` data embedded:

```
Astcart.Application.FIXTURES=[
    {
        ...
        "logged_in": {
            "id": "1",
            "logged": true,
            "username": "sac1245",
            "account_id": "4214"
        },
        ...
    }
];
```

So the `logged_in` property mapping need the parameter `embedded: true`, to be able to find this data, as follow:

```
Astcart.Application =  Ember.Model.extend({
  ...
  logged_in: Ember.belongsTo('Astcart.Logged_in', {key: 'logged_in', embedded: true })
});
```

Without this it will try to query for the `Astcart.Logged_in`:

```
Astcart.Logged_in.find(1)
```

and because it doesn't have an adapter, will fail with the exception: `Uncaught Error: Ember.Adapter must implement findQuery`

You can see this working in that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8zjsh/